# Ionic 6. Google maps not being displayed after updating to cordova 10.0.0

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, google-api

As soon as updated cordova to version 10.0.0. My map view is just blank. No error is being thrown. I am sharing the Ionic info and dependency list below. I have tried creating a new API ke and adding it to the app nothing is working.

**Info:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (/home/abhishyam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.2
   native-run (update available: 1.4.1)   : 1.2.2

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/abhishyam/android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.19.0 (/home/abhishyam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.9
   OS                : Linux 5.4
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nearby-restaurants",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "cordova-android": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "YOUR_API_KEY"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**src/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
</script>
</html>
```

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  Marker,
  GoogleMapsAnimation,
  MyLocation,
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  map: GoogleMap;
  address: string;
  constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController, private platform: Platform) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    // Since ngOnInit() is executed before `deviceready` event,
    // you have to wait the event.
    await this.platform.ready();
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741704,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    });
    // this.goToMyLocation();
  }

  goToMyLocation() {
    this.map.clear();

    // Get the location of you
    this.map
      .getMyLocation()
      .then((location: MyLocation) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null, 2));

        // Move the map camera to the location with animation
        this.map.animateCamera({
          target: location.latLng,
          zoom: 17,
          duration: 5000,
        });

        //add a marker
        let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
          title: '@ionic-native/google-maps plugin!',
          snippet: 'This plugin is awesome!',
          position: location.latLng,
          animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.BOUNCE,
        });

        //show the infoWindow
        marker.showInfoWindow();

        //If clicked it, display the alert
        marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
          this.showToast('clicked!');
        });

        this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log('Click MAP', data);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        //this.loading.dismiss();
        this.showToast(err.error_message);
      });
  }

  async showToast(message: string) {
    let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'middle',
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

As soon as updated cordova to version 10.0.0. My map view is just blank. No error is being thrown. I am sharing the Ionic info and dependency list below. I have tried creating a new API ke and adding it to the app nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still an ongoing issue about the ionic native google maps in Cordova 10. As per the github ticket the issue is:

> It's not related to your target Android version. It's cause by change
> from 4.0.x to 4.1.x of AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) Prior to AGP 4.1.+,
> ***assert*** keyword was not enforced.
>
> Latest Cordova-Android started using AGP 4.1.+, which is causing the
> ***AssertionError***

Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/issues/365) for the github issue.

There is an ***unofficial fix*** you can try which is not yet merged to the mapsplugin:master branch. You can read from this [link](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/pull/2872). You can try and fork the repo but ***note*** *that the fix is not intended for production usage as per the author.*

> Please note my fork is not intended for production usage.
>
> That said, there shouldn't be any changes related to map markers in
> the fork.
>
> If you find the issue. Feel free to suggest a PR

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.